# Realistic plan for the construction of a stone pyramid (actually tetrahedron)

Tags: internal-consistency, megastructures

I am working on a story set in the present where one of the minor subplots involves a billionaire building a giant stone tetrahedron out in the Nevada desert.  While it is not critical for the plot for it to be super realistic, I would like to include some realistic details for background color.

- How large can such a structure be made?  The current pyramid is around 140m.  Could we make it 200?  500?  1000?  I assume at some size it would weigh so much it would just liquefy the earth's crust beneath it.
- Where would one get the stone?  A tetrahedron that is 500m/side would need almost 15 million cubic meters of stone.  What stone would be realistic?  Still granite/limestone?  For this type of project, would someone just contract with existing quarries?
- Any thoughts on logistics?  I assume for a project of this size one would build railroads as needed from the quarries to the build site, and assembly could be done using pretty standard construction cranes.  Any other details I should toss in?
- Any thoughts on construction time or cost?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We can't do the whole design and logistic chain for you. Please give us just one problem at a time.

Comment: Is it solid (so effectively an artificial mountain) or hollow?  Does it need to be made of stone at all?  Also, the materials and labour to reproduce the Great Pyramid has been [estimated at $5B](https://www.livescience.com/18589-cost-build-great-pyramid-today.html), and the volume increases by the cube of the height, so something twice as high as the Great Pyramid could be expected to cost ~$40B, putting it in reach of only [22 people in the world](https://www.businessinsider.in/thelife/personalities/news/top-100-richest-people-in-the-world/articleshow/74415418.cms).

Comment: You should look up the alberta sulfur pyramid.

Answer (score 7):

**Consider Mount Everest**

Generally speaking, mountain ranges do affect the tectonic plates below them, but they do not "liquefy the crust." So several cubic kilometres of rock **can** be placed on the bedrock, if not on soft soil. The Nazis considered building monuments in Berlin during WWII. What actually happened was the [heavy load-bearing body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwerbelastungsk%C3%B6rper), a big chunk of concrete that has slowly been sinking into the soft Berlin soil ever since. The first step might have to be to remove soil down to the bedrock for the foundations.

**Consider the ore and coal trade**

In the present day, look at the [MS Ore Brazil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS_Ore_Brasil), a large ore carrier with 400,000 tons capacity. Calculate how many roundtrips of such a ship would be required. Of course ships don't go to Nevada, but it gives you a benchmark for the loads which are routinely moved. I **don't** suggest that the stone comes from another continent, just that loads of that size routinely go from mines, to trains, to ships, back into trains, to the steelworks.

A 'mere' single-digit billionaire might not be able to afford that. The richest persons on Earth? Probably ...

Comment: In the Netherlands the solid foundation can only be found deeper inside soft soil. Depending on the weight and the ground it covers, they drive large poles into the ground to sufficiently strong layers for support. It isn't a stretch to do that in the desert either.

Comment: @Trioxidane Fellow dutchman here! I'm sorry to inform you that building on poles as we do has severe limitations on the weight of the the structure. Practically speaking, for something as massive as described here, you would need a single massive pole that goes right through the sand layers we usually rest our poles on to bedrock that is very (as in impossibly) deep under the surface. Otherwise, it would sink through the ground creating waves of soil that could destroy entire neighborhoods (that's why there is a max on how high builders are allowed to stack sand and stone debris).

Comment: Thanks! Clearly I need to brush up on my knowledge how it works. But would a single large pole work? Regardless, each is additional weight added to the bedrock. With what you're saying, could it work at all on soft soil?

Answer (score 7):

**Carve it from a larger stone.**

[image: sandstone cliff]

https://www.nps.gov/zion/learn/nature/navajo.htm

Depicted - a cliff of Navajo Sandstone, a prevalent stone type in the Nevada desert.  I estimate this cliff to be 250 meters.  You might find bigger ones.  It is holding itself up.

Rather than import and stack blocks, cut and blast away the sides of a larger rock to produce a pyramid shape.  It might be rough and so you might need to finish it with and exterior cladding of blocks.  Fortunately you will have a lot of material  for making blocks.

Comment: I like this idea!  Especially from the vanity standpoint, where the character could spark some outrage by buying a mountain in a place like Zion from the government.

Answer (score 3):

If the requirement is full stone you bind yourself. With many modern techniques you can build solid structures and then cover the outside with stone. This makes the inside more practical and can be larger.

The height is of less consequence. Normally you need to take care about wind and balance etc. With a pyramid it's relatively stable by my knowledge, although I would still ask a real building specialist. But according to my knowledge, a Burj Khalifa height or higher should easilly be possible as it stands more stable with the weight more spread out. If they include further wind and elements architecture, it should be able to reach incredible heights.

The idea has been further thought out in real life to be an actual mountain.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Berg_Komt_Er

This will give you the basic idea, but it might've been hollow, filled with shops, adventures and possibly housing, besides the normal mountain activities.

Edit: the link might give you a better idea about materials and such, as well as scaling down might for the costs.

Comment: Thanks!  In this case, the story requires a solid structure with no useful role, just a monument.

Comment: I'll defer to structural engineers posting here then. A solid structure is more difficult because of it's weight, but I saw (and upvoted) some clever answers already. You'll get there :)

Answer (score 1):

- Yes. I mean you can made it any height you want. Phisical limitation for Nevada desert would be around 5-7 km. Exceeding this will not liquefy earth, but can case earthquakes, wich would desroy that structure
- There are a lot of sandstone (and other sedimentary minerals) in Nevada desert (you know - those spectacular pillars). You would need from couple to dozen of this (depending on size) if you stay reasonable.
- You would not need a crane. Yuo may use low layer as a base for your roads/rail network.  Exactly like piramids in Egipt were biuld. They used "inverse quarry" road pattern to deliver blocks up to the top.
- 10-100 Billons, and 1-20 years of production for 140m - 1000m piramid. This estamation is closer to the top (i.e with perfect oganization 150m piramid can be build in half of a year)

Comment: There is not a lot of sandstone in the Nevada desert.  It's mostly granite & igneous rocks. You'll find some in southern Nevada, but those spectacular pillars are mostly in Utah & Arizona.